# dropdown onselectedindexchanged event not firing and value kept on postback c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, postback, dropdown

I can't get the dropdown `onselectedindexchanged` event to fire, and when I make a selection it resets the value of the dropdown `onpostback`, even though I have the `if (!ispostback)` in the page load event.

this is a content page in a master page in asp in case that matters.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>                   
    <asp:DropDownList ID="EventSVCProgList" runat="server" 
      EnableViewState="true" 
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="EventSVCProgList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
      AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection constr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CBTestDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand eventsvcprogCMD = new SqlCommand("select*from SvcProg where eventatteligable=1", constr); // table name 
        SqlDataAdapter eventsvcadapt = new SqlDataAdapter(eventsvcprogCMD);
        DataSet eventsvcset = new DataSet();
        constr.Open();
        eventsvcadapt.Fill(eventsvcset);  // fill dataset
        EventSVCProgList.DataTextField = eventsvcset.Tables[0].Columns["SvcProgID"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
        EventSVCProgList.DataValueField = eventsvcset.Tables[0].Columns["eventatteligable"].ToString();
        EventSVCProgList.DataSource = eventsvcset.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
        EventSVCProgList.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist

        constr.Close();
    }

}

protected void EventSVCProgList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Eat Poop");
    var somevalue = EventSVCProgList.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: please add this to page load and test : `if(IsPostBack) return;`

Comment: Please check that Page level or any parent control's ViewState is disabled?

Comment: Apart from that, using Messagebox.Show in Web is bad practice. because it will show Message box on server. i guess it added just for testing purpose ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help.  its still not working so i'm just going to try to use javascript instead. its got to be some fundamental flaw with the way the master page or content page is setup.

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out.

it was because i was not using a unique value for the following code:EventSVCProgList.DataValueField = eventsvcset.Tables[0].Columns["eventatteligable"].ToString();  eventatteligable is the same value for all available selections in dropdown.  i changed this to the column with unique values and it worked.  feel really stupid.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things.

1) You need to add a Script Manager to the page at the top if not added already(it will give you a runtime error if you have not added a script Manager to the page)

2) You need to change the Update Panel content as shown below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="EventSVCProgList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EventSVCProgList_SelectedIndexChanged">

            </asp:DropDownList>

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="EventSVCProgList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems that any parent control or page leven ViewState is disabled. please check in debug mode that what value you getting for EventSVCProgList.EnableViewState and other parent controls' as well.